# move text box outside the textwidth

Tags: boxes, text-decorations

I used tcolorbox to make a semi-transparent box as explained [in this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199659/text-with-semi-transparent-color-filled-box). What I need is to offset this box from the center of the texwidth, this means crossing a bit the border of the textwidth. Is there a way to achieve this with tcolorbox? I tried flushright environment but the box doesn't go further than the textwidth border.

Any hint is appreciated, thanks in advance,

tcolorbox code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newtcolorbox{frontcoverbox}[1][]{
    width=0.7\textwidth,
    %arc=3mm,
    %auto outer arc,
    boxsep=0cm,
    toprule=1pt,
    leftrule=1pt,
    bottomrule=1pt,
    rightrule=1pt,
    colframe=white,
    fontupper=\raggedleft\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\itshape,
    breakable,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    opacityframe=0.35,
    opacityback=0.35
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontcoverbox}[]
    \textbf{Photo:} yaba daba du\\
    \textbf{Place:} de la refurinfunflai\\
    \textbf{Provided by:} Krusty the Clown
\end{frontcoverbox}

\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

Based on this code, adding `enlarge left by=5cm` to the frontcoverbox did the trick, thanks to Harish Kumar for that!

Comment: Perhaps you should try `\rlap{\tcolorbox{…}}`.

Comment: Please always post _complete_ documents not just fragments so people can reproduce exactly what you are seeing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry about that, always the MWE =) I think that should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}     %% you left [many], needed for breakable option
\usepackage{showframe}

\newtcolorbox{frontcoverbox}[1][]{
    width=0.7\textwidth,
    before=\hskip2.5\textwidth,
    %arc=3mm,
    %auto outer arc,
    boxsep=0cm,
    toprule=1pt,
    leftrule=1pt,
    bottomrule=1pt,
    rightrule=1pt,
    colframe=white,
    fontupper=\raggedleft\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\itshape,
    breakable,
    nobeforeafter,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    opacityframe=0.35,
    opacityback=0.35,
    enlarge left by=1in,    %% this one here pushed to right
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontcoverbox}[]
    \textbf{Photo:} yaba daba du\\
    \textbf{Place:} de la refurinfunflai\\
    \textbf{Provided by:} Krusty the Clown
\end{frontcoverbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]